# c++ bitwise shift of long long int's in vector for example by 380 bits

Tags: c++, vector, vectorization, bit-shift

i am searching for a efficient way to bitwise shift the whole vector of long long int's. The whole vector should be shifted not just each value separately. The shift value can be random for example shifting by 380 or 2000 bit to the right. Is there a efficient way for doing this in c++?

```
void bitwiseRightShiftFunction(std::vector<uint64_t>& values, uint64_t shiftValue){ ?? values = values >> shiftValue;}
```

Comment: There is no efficient way to do this in C++. Just write the code. Obviously you should split the shift into two parts, one part is a whole number of 64 bit shifts, this part is efficient, but you will still be left with a <64 bit shift.

Comment: BTW `long long int` is not `uint64_t`

Comment: It might be worth looking at a big integer library to see how they handle this, GMP for example.

Comment: If `values` vector is very large, and you're using newer than C++17, you can look into `std::transform_reduce()` algorithm for parallel processing of right shift operation.

Comment: Can you use `std::bitset` instead of `std::vector<uint64_t>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does an in-place, bitwise, right-shift for a vector of `uint64_t` assuming the last vector element is on the right, i.e. the least significant. It is a straight forward implementation but efficient. This code along with a simple driver can be found in the GitHub repo [cpp-core/so](https://github.com/cpp-core/so.git).

Function:

```cpp
#include "core/util/tool.h"
#include "core/util/random.h"

// Shift the bits in `a` by `n` bits to the right (towards lesser
// signifigance assuming that a[0] is the most significant word)
// prepending with zero bits as necessary.
void right_shift(std::vector<uint64_t>& a, size_t n) {
    constexpr auto bits_per_word = sizeof(uint64_t) * CHAR_BIT;

    // Parition n into the number of a number of whole words to shift and the
    // remaining number of bits to shift.
    auto words_to_shift = n / bits_per_word;
    auto bits_to_shift = n % bits_per_word;

    // Create a bit mask that covers the upper `bits_to_shift`
    // bits in a word. The value `(uint64_t{1} << bits_to_shift) -
    // 1` is the lower `bits_to_shift` bits so the bit reversal
    // turns them into the upper `bits_to_shift` bits.
    auto mask = __builtin_bitreverse64((uint64_t{1} << bits_to_shift) - 1);

    // The words in range [0,limit) are the only bits that will appear
    // in the result because words in range [limit,a.size) are shifted
    // "off the end". Starting with the least significant word, loop
    // over all the words that will contribute bits to the result
    // (possibly none).
    for (int src_idx = a.size() - words_to_shift - 1; src_idx >= 0; --src_idx) {
        // In general this source word will be split between the two
        // destination words left and right (least significant). The
        // lower `bits_to_shift` bits will go to the upper bits of the
        // right word while the upper bits will become the lower bits
        // of the left word.
        auto rdx = src_idx + words_to_shift + 1;
        auto ldx = src_idx + words_to_shift;

        // Get the source value and rotate it `bits_to_shift` bits to
        // the right so that the bits are aligned with their
        // eventual destinations.
        auto value = __builtin_rotateright64(a[src_idx], bits_to_shift);

        if (rdx < a.size())
            a[rdx] |= value bitand mask;
        a[ldx] = value bitand ~mask;
    }

    // Prepend with zeros as necessary
    for (auto i = 0; i < words_to_shift; ++i)
        a[i] = 0;
}
```

Test program:

```cpp
int tool_main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    ArgParse opts
        (
         argValue<'n'>("number-bits", 512, "Number bits"),
         argValue<'m'>("shift", 380, "Right shift M bits"),
         argFlag<'v'>("verbose", "Verbose diagnostics")
         );
    opts.parse(argc, argv);
    auto n = opts.get<'n'>();
    auto m = opts.get<'m'>();
    // auto verbose = opts.get<'v'>();

    std::vector<uint64_t> bits(1 + n / 64);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint64_t> d;
    for (auto& value : bits)
        value = d(core::rng());

    cout << std::string(m, ' ');
    for (const auto& value : bits)
        cout << fmt::format("{:064b}", value);
    cout << endl;

    right_shift(bits, m);
    for (const auto& value : bits)
        cout << fmt::format("{:064b}", value);
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```bash
$ make right_shift && right_shift -n 64 -m 17
.................11010000100100011011101101011100001000101010111010011110111101101110011111100001111110101110111011010101110000110001111101111001
00000000000000000110100001001000110111011010111000010001010101110100111101111011011100111111000011111101011101110110101011100001
```